# Unable to execute scroll jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

I am trying to run below code while implementing appending data in scrolling window :

```
$.get(URL,function(data){           
    $(".daily_list").append(data);
    page++; 
    isLoading=false;            
    $(".loadingText").hide();                       
});
```

But unfortunately, application is not reaching to line below  $(".daily_list").append(data); where I am trying to initialize other variable after loading data. I am also not getting any error so please suggest.

Comment: try putting a console.log after line 2. It is not very clear what is going wrong here.

Comment: What is the value of `URL`?

Comment: Please check  my function :                                          $(window).scroll(function() {
  
       if (isLoading==false && $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()-$("#footer").height()) {
    
    isLoading=true;
    $(".loadingText").show();
     var URL="/dailyUpdateListLoding.do?mode=few&page="+page;
    $.get(URL,function(data){   
        $(".daily_list").append(data);
        page++;  
        isLoading=false;    
        $(".loadingText").hide();       
       
     });

     }
  });

Comment: Though application is appending data on the screen after scrolling but I am unable to find the reason why It is not executing lines after ".append".. In below code I am getting alert("Before") but not alert("after"). Please help me on the same.         $.get(URL,function(data){  
      alert("Before");
        $(".daily_list").append(data);
        alert("After");
        page++;  
        isLoading=false;    
        $(".loadingText").hide(); 
       
       
     });

Comment: Hi Team, Please help me out.